# Count Total Number of Radio Button Changed

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have rows of radio buttons with a default check on one of the radio button on each row.

I would like to count the total radio button that gets changed after the page loads. (Not total number of times the radio button is clicked)

---

rd1     rd2   rd3      rd4     rd5

rd6     rd7    rd8     rd9     rd10

rd11    rd12   rd13    rd14    rd15

---

rd1, rd6, rd11 is checked by default on page loads, so when a user now checks rd2 the total should say 1, if he checks rd8 next total should say 2, if he checks rd3, the total should remain as 2, if the user checks rd15 total should say 3, if he checks rd11 total should still say 3

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/19eggs/jj4Uv/1/)

```
$("input:radio").click(function() {
var totalRd = $('input:radio:checked').length;
$("#totalRd .rd-count").html(totalRd);
});
```

It is possible to check the radio button by default without the "check" word in the input tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can filter it, following your example:

[DEMO jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jj4Uv/2/)

```
$("input:radio").click(function () {
    var totalRd = $('table').find(':not(.pend) > input:radio:checked').length;
    $("#totalRd .rd-count").html(totalRd);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var totalChercks=0;
 $('input:radio').each(function() {
      if($(this).is(':checked')) {
         totalChercks+=1;
      }
      else {
          totalChercks=totalChercks;
      }
    });
```

Comment: Thank you. I decided to go with A Wolff's solution as it was much easier to implement.

Answer (score 1):

You can use psudo class. Also added anonymous function for clarity..

http://jsfiddle.net/jFIT/jj4Uv/3/

```
$.fn.changedChecker = function () {
 $(this).click(function () {     
$(this).closest('tr').find('.changedRad').removeClass('changedRad');
    $(this).addClass('changedRad');
});
}

$("input:radio").changedChecker();

$('input[type=button]').click(function () {
 alert($('.changedRad').length);
});
```

Comment: Thank you JF it. I decided to go with A Wolff's solution as it was much easier to implement.